# Unresolved inclusion when using different sysroot

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, inclusion

On Eclipse 3.8 is not finding any headers when I add `--sysroot=<path to new root>` option for compilation. I already added the same option to the Discovery options, if did not add this option eclipse finds headers in old location.

Any clue what could be wrong?